# Python: Passed two arrays as function arguments. Expecting a series but only the last value is returned

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, pandas, numpy

I believe there are other ways of doing this but I wish to learn why I am getting the results that I am getting.

For added context, I am trying to learn vectorization in python and I came across tutorials that show passing the arrays is quicker than say the .apply() method.

Aim: Compare two boolean arrays, and based on multiple conditions, return a result which should also be a series.

However, doing the below I am only getting the value of the last combination not the series of results.

```
bool_1 = np.array([True,False,False])
bool_2 = np.array([False,True,False])

# Categorise the outcomes


def bool_combinations(bool_array_1,bool_array_2):
    
    if bool_array_1 is True:
        OUTCOME = "Outcome 1"
    
    elif bool_array_2 is True:
        OUTCOME = "Outcome 2"
    
    else:
        OUTCOME = "Outcome 3"
    
    print(bool_array_1,bool_array_2,OUTCOME)
    return OUTCOME
   
    
bool_combinations(bool_1,bool_2)
```

From the above I get the output of:

```
[ True False False] [False  True False] Outcome 3
'Outcome 3'
```

I was hoping for a result which looks more like:

```
[ True False False] [False  True False] [ 'Outcome 1' 'Outcome 2' 'Outcome 3']
[ 'Outcome 1' 'Outcome 2' 'Outcome 3']
```

Comment: did you want to iterate those arrays and test the elements?

Comment: @JonSG Yes, idealy I will be iterating through the two arrays... i.e. for the first iteration it would compare bool_1 = True, and bool_2 = False. and as Bool_1 is True the outcome should be "Outcome 1"

Comment: @Forensic_07 if I use '==' I get this error: "ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()"

Comment: What does it mean to you that a list of True and False is True?

Comment: @Stefan I wish to look at each element of the two arrays, instead of the lists as a whole. So the first value of array 1 and first value of array 2... then move to the second values etc.

Comment: Deleted my comment because I didn't notice these were numpy arrays.

Answer (score 0):

You are close, but you likely want to zip the arrays together and compare element by element rather than comparing the arrays for truthiness. The reason you got "Outcome 3" is that:

```
numpy.array([...]) is True ## ---> is always False
```

Using your code as a base, you might try:

```
import numpy

def bool_combinations(bool_array_1,bool_array_2):
    OUTCOME = []
    for (bool1, bool2) in zip(bool_array_1,bool_array_2):
        if bool1:
            OUTCOME.append("Outcome 1")
        elif bool2:
            OUTCOME.append("Outcome 2")
        else:
            OUTCOME.append("Outcome 3")
    return OUTCOME

bool_1 = numpy.array([True,False,False])
bool_2 = numpy.array([False,True,False])
print(bool_combinations(bool_1,bool_2))
```

That will give you:

```
['Outcome 1', 'Outcome 2', 'Outcome 3']
```

I might personally do:

```
import numpy

def bool_combinations(bool_array_1,bool_array_2):
    def _get_outcome(bool1, bool2):
        if bool1: return "Outcome 1"
        if bool2: return "Outcome 2"
        return "Outcome 3"

    return [_get_outcome(bool1, bool2) for bool1, bool2 in zip(bool_array_1,bool_array_2)]

bool_1 = numpy.array([True,False,False])
bool_2 = numpy.array([False,True,False])
print(bool_combinations(bool_1,bool_2))
```

That will also give you:

```
['Outcome 1', 'Outcome 2', 'Outcome 3']
```

You can get golfier still, but I don't think making it shorter results in easier code to understand.